# Open select ie6

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-6

I searched for a way to open a select element (combobox like) in ie6 from javascript.

```
document.getElementById("sel1").click();
```

This method works fine in Firefox but doesn't in ie6. So does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain it isn't possible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Darhazer: I disagree. If what the OP is asking is simply not possible (which I'm pretty certain it isn't), no other answer will do.

Comment: "I don't believe" is not the same as "it's not possible", Please provide references to your answer

Comment: @Darhazer: Unless some Microsoft documentation specifically mentions that it is not possible to expand a select list programmatically (and I haven't seen any, after a little searching) then there is no authoritative reference I could possibly provide. API documentation tends to focus on what the API does do more than what it doesn't. I've provided a non-authoritative answer based on my (fairly extensive) experience of IE 6's DOM API; it is what it is, and I think it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Darhazer: For example, [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536363%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) seems to be pretty much the sum total of official documentation on the `click()` method in IE. It mentions that the `click()` method cannot be used to move the focus to an element, which is not the same thing as being asked in this question and is therefore not much help as a reference.